# Quick Share Fresco cached image Via Intent

Tags: android, fresco

**Wants faster and quick process for share fresco cached image form loacl storage**

> fresco returning bitmap with callback some time it takes time for fetching image.
>
> Not able to share direct bitmap via intent needs for store image temp first and then share file path URI of image.

```
            ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder
                    .newBuilderWithSource(httpUri(article.getImage())).setAutoRotateEnabled(true)
                    .build();
            ImagePipeline imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline();
            final DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>
                    dataSource = imagePipeline.fetchDecodedImage(imageRequest, view.getContext());
            dataSource.subscribe(new BaseBitmapDataSubscriber() {
                @Override
                public void onNewResultImpl(@Nullable Bitmap bitmap) {
                    if (dataSource.isFinished() && bitmap != null) {
                        String pathofBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(view.getContext().getContentResolver(), bitmap, "APp", null);
                        Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);
                        ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from((Activity) parent.getContext())
                                .setChooserTitle(R.string.share)
                                .setText(format("%s via App %s", title, ""))
                                .setSubject(format("%s via App", title))
                                .setStream(bmpUri)
                                .setType("image/jpeg")
                                .startChooser();
                        dataSource.close();

                    }
                    dataSource.close();
                }
```

Comment: [sharing-an-image-from-fresco](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Fresco-Library#sharing-an-image-from-fresco)

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1):

When you are constructing your ImageRequest above, add this line:

```
.setLowestPermittedRequestLevel(BITMAP_MEMORY_CACHE)
```

Then you can assume that the data source will return instantly, and you can call `DataSource.hasResult()` and `DataSource.getResult()` to get your bitmap instantly.

You still have to follow the [rules for closeable references](http://frescolib.org/docs/closeable-references.html#_).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a different approach. Just using a postProcessor to get the bitmap.

```
setPostprocessor(new BasePostprocessor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.process(bitmap);
                draweeBitmap = bitmap;

            }
        });
```

Now you have your bitmap, so you can save somewhere in the app. folder or SD card and share it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use closeableimage you need to use CloseableAnimatedImage.
I am struggling with the same issue.